# Where can i find a specification for the Network Lock Manager v4 protocol?

Tags: nfs

I am trying to debug locks interactions between NFSv3 clients and server and i am unable to correctly interpret their exchanges (using wireshark).

[rfc1813 NFS Version 3 Protocol Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813#page-114) says nothing has changed:

> **6.2 NLM Procedures**
>
> The procedures in the NLM version 4 protocol are semantically
> the same as those in the NLM version 3 protocol.

but the previous [NFS: Network File System Protocol Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1094) doesn't say anything about NLM.

So far, I've ended up reading [Linux kernel source code](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=fs/lockd/svcproc.c) but I would like to find a documentation that explains how the protocol works, the list of procedures and their use, etc. I think I need the full specification but a statechart would also be nice?

Could someone point me to the correct RFC ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no applicable RFC. The OpenGroup seems to have inherited the XNFS specification which is available here: https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/c702